# upload file issues ( ASP.NET)

Tags: asp.net

I want to upload the excel file to the `Upload` folder. But I have set the path properly in my controller, no idea how this error can be happen. Attached the controller code and error screen shot.

Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadBatch(LogonUser logonUser, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    JsonResultModel result = new JsonResultModel();
    RegexUtilities util = new RegexUtilities();

    try
    {
        foreach (HttpPostedFileBase file in files)
        {
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            string upDir = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "Upload", DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss"));
            string path = Path.Combine(upDir, fileName);

            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.Status = JsonResultStatus.Failed;
        result.Message = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Error screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The error says this is an invalid path. Does that folder exist? Nothing creates the folder in the code and `DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss")` makes it highly unlikely that some other code could have created the folder in advance

Comment: As for the error message, log the *entire* exception text, not just the message.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos yes folder exits,   folder name is Upload

Comment: No, the folder name is `171724` and nobody created it.

Comment: i created folder manually in the certain path.

Comment: That would require creating the folder in the same second as the request. That's impossible. In any case the error is clear. It says the path is wrong, because one of the folders doesn't exist. Use `Directory.CreateDirectory(upDir)` to create the folder first

Comment: string upDir = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, "Upload", DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss"));
string dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(upDir);
string path = Path.Combine(dir, fileName);

file.SaveAs(path);

Comment: mean like this ?

Comment: The return value of `Directory.CreateDirectory` is a `DirectoryInfo`. You don't need to use it though. You already have the path string, its' `upDir`. Just call `Directory.CreateDirectory(upDir)` before `file.SaveAs`

Comment: ok the problem solved. Thank you